# CUDA kernel for finding the min and max index of values in a 1D array greater than particular threshold

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, reduction

I am trying to write a CUDA kernel that is used to find min and max index of values in 1D array greater than a particular threshold
Below is the pseudo code in CPU for doing the same

```
int min_index = 0, max_index = length;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] >= threshold)
        {
            min_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = length - 1 ; i >= min_index; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i] >= threshold)
        {
            max_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

One way of doing this is GPU is using atomic operations, but i would not prefer to use them. I was thinking of using reduction, but unable to figure out the logic with which i need to do reduction. For min reduction a logic like below can be followed

```
    for(int i = 8; i >= 1; i /= 2)
    {
        if(threadIdx.x < i)
            sh_mem[threadIdx.x] = min(sh_mem[threadIdx.x], sh_mem[threadIdx.x + i]);
        __syncthreads();
    }
```

But what logic can i use to do for my case, where i need to compare the values in shared memory with a threshold and compute the min index in shared memory satisfying this criteria?

Would greatly appreciate any thoughts on how to solve the above problem

EDIT: It is not possible for me to use thrust library due to some constraints

Comment: Atomics seem like an easy and fast way to do this. Why don't you want to use them? You could also limit the number of them by using a [grid strided loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) and only do the atomics at the very end. Or you run it through a [reduction with Thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#reductions) but that looks like overkill

Comment: From my previous encounter with atomics, the performance was bad, so i was under impression to use atomics only if there is no alternative possible. I know the performance with atomics is dependent on number of times it is used. Maybe with  above grid strided loop the number of times atomics is called might come down and performance also might improve. But i am curious if there is better alternative than atomics for the above case

Comment: In terms of Thrust algorithms this is rather a [`find_if`](https://nvidia.github.io/cccl/thrust/api/groups/group__searching.html#function-find-if). Although using a general reduction has the benefit of being able to combine both searches.

Comment: It is so that what you are really trying to do is bracket the interval where the array values lie above the threshold value? That is not a classical reduction nor a good fit for a reduction in general, I would say

Comment: Exactly @talonmies. 
Can you please suggest any better approach for solving the above problem?

Comment: A single thread group scanning through the array, using shared memory atomics to implement the `break` should work. With a grid-strided loop and global memory atomics, you can also have multiple blocks scanning. I think the worst-case performance will be lower than a simple reduction over the whole array but that might simply need some benchmarking

Comment: FYI: `thrust::find_if` is [currently implemented](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cccl/blob/52308191d7db8455d5f28e55312ca3de5916ec09/thrust/thrust/system/cuda/detail/find.h#L154-L175) as a sequential loop over intervals of the original range calling `reduce` on each. The loop allows for an early-out in case something is found. The comments also mention an optimization idea: "compose find_if from a look-back prefix scan algorithm and abort kernel when the first element is found"

Comment: @paleonix
Sorry, I missed to add this in my question. For my solution i am not allowed to use thrust

Comment: Understanding how Thrust is doing it might help doing it yourself. Also StackOverflow Q&As are primarily aimed at future readers which might be able to utilize Thrust.

Comment: Okay @paleonix, i will check the thrust implementation of find_if functionality as you mentioned

Comment: Thrust was mentioned as a possible solution in the very first comment and you didn't think to amend your question with your arbitrary restrictions until an answer was posted?! I hope you understand how disrespectful this is to people who invest their time to answer your questions.

Comment: @Homer512
I accept that, i have done a mistake. I missed to reply back to first comment mentioning thrust. I sincerely apologize for my oversight

Comment: Back to the topic at hand: Given that this problem is bandwidth-bound, avoiding unnecessary global reads is a priority and therefore early exiting is a must. Using global atomics makes that early exit very easy because every block can check the global results to see if the block still has to run/load values from global memory or if it can just retire. Reduction schemes that work without global atomics give little chance for that early exit. So in this particular case atomics have much more benefits than drawbacks, I would think.

Comment: In comparison Thrusts early exit has a lot of host-device synchronization which one wants to avoid. A single kernel (per `find_if`) solution without intermittent synchronization also has the advantage that you can do min and max in parallel using two streams.

Comment: "i need to compare the values in shared memory with a threshold" the values should never enter shared memory, just their indices. Just like with `thrust::transform_reduce()`, replace indices of values below the threshold with "neutral" indices, i.e. `INT_MAX` for `min()` and `INT_MIN` for `max()`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a sample of how to do this in Thrust with a single algorithm instead of two calls to `thrust::find_if` (one utilizing `reverse_iterator`s). This implementation is using a single `transform_reduce` where the `transform` filters out the values above the threshold by replacing them with neutral elements and prepares the following `minmax` reduction working on tuples.

While it might be possible to get better performance using a custom kernel as discussed in the comments below the question, this should serve as a good reference solution (i.e. this isn't necessarily supposed to be the final/accepted answer).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/zip_function.h>

int main() {
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vals{0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 42.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    thrust::device_vector<float> vals(h_vals);
    float threshold = 42.0f;

    const auto enumerate_iter = thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple(
            thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
            vals.cbegin()));
    const auto filter_minmax_input = thrust::make_zip_function(
            [threshold] __host__ __device__ (int idx, float val) {
                if (val >= threshold) {
                    return thrust::make_tuple(idx, idx);
                }
                else {
                    return thrust::make_tuple(INT_MAX, INT_MIN);
                }
            });
    const auto minmax_f = 
        [] __host__ __device__ (thrust::tuple<int, int> left,
                                thrust::tuple<int, int> right) {
            const int left_min_idx = thrust::get<0>(left);
            const int left_max_idx = thrust::get<1>(left);
            const int right_min_idx = thrust::get<0>(right);
            const int right_max_idx = thrust::get<1>(right);
            return thrust::make_tuple(
                thrust::min(left_min_idx, right_min_idx),
                thrust::max(left_max_idx, right_max_idx));
        };
    const auto res = thrust::transform_reduce(
        enumerate_iter, enumerate_iter + vals.size(),
        filter_minmax_input,
        thrust::make_tuple(INT_MAX, INT_MIN),
        minmax_f);
    
    std::cout << thrust::get<0>(res) << ' ' << thrust::get<1>(res) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in case the minimum and maximum indices are far apart, the two `find_if`s should actually **perform better**, assuming they do implement early exit and avoid reading the whole range from global memory. In the (edge-) case where these indices are very close however a single reduction **might** be favorable as it avoids overheads.

Because it is probably (did not benchmark) the better solution in general, I will include the (pretty simple) `find_if` solution here as well:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/find.h>

int main() {
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vals{0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 42.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    thrust::device_vector<float> vals(h_vals);
    float threshold = 42.0f;

    const auto filter = [threshold] __host__ __device__ (float val){
            return val >= threshold;
        };
    const auto min_idx = thrust::distance(
        vals.cbegin(),
        thrust::find_if(vals.cbegin(), vals.cend(), filter));
    const auto max_idx = thrust::distance(
        thrust::find_if(vals.crbegin(), vals.crend(), filter),
        vals.crend() - 1); // reverse iterator corresponding to cbegin
    
    std::cout << min_idx << ' ' << max_idx << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed solution. But unfortunately, i am not allowed to use thrust for my case

Comment: @Sampath neither CUB (used in the backend of Thrust, included with the CUDA Toolkit)?

Comment: Yes. Basically, i cannot use any library that provides readymade optimized kernels

Comment: And the reason is that this is some educational exercise? Note that editing a question in a way that makes existing answers obsolete is frowned upon. I recommend rolling back that restriction and just not accepting this answer to motivate more answers to be given.

Comment: This is not for educational exercise. This is the guidelines given for my project for which i am working on. So my hands are tied on this

Comment: If people want to pay you to reinvent the wheel that is rather their problem than yours or mine, I guess ;) Just keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a Forum. Answers (and questions) are (in theory) aimed at people that may have a similar problem in the future. They might have less restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It is inefficient to wholly avoid the use of atomics, but you can reduce their usage quite a bit, by doing reduction per warp.
If you have Ampere or better, you'll have the [`__reduce_XXX_sync`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-reduce-functions) functions, which I'll do what you want. Note that in actual testing, a warpwide atomicOp on a shared mem is actually faster (12 cycles vs 26 cycles), but you did ask to not use atomic operations.

Testing a predicate can be done very efficiently using [`__ballot_sync`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions). This tests 32 predicates in parallel. One more reduction and you can do 1024 tests in four instructions (see code below). With some bit twiddling we can derive the first thread to find a match and use that to derive the index of the match.

This code is obviously memory limited, you can make it faster by using [`async_memcpy`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-data-copies) (new in Ampere, preview feature in Volta) to prefetch memory ahead of time (out of scope for this answer though).
My tests indicate that this will speed it up by about 30%.

Note that atomic operations on the GPU are very very fast, a few cycles, even for atomic operations on global memory. This is unlike atomics on CPUs that takes 1000's of cycles.

If you model the atomics as fire-and-forget operations (i.e.: do not use the return value), they return immediately.

```
static constexpr auto big = 0x0FFFFFFF;
static constexpr auto small = 0;

__device__ [[nodiscard]] int laneid() { return threadIdx.x % 32; }
__device__ [[nodiscard]] int warpid() { return threadIdx.x / 32; }

template <int blockcount, blocksize>
__device__ int findminmax(int* data, int length, int threshold) {
    constexpr auto warpcount = blocksize / 32;
    const auto warpid = (threadIdx.x / 32);
    __shared__ int minlocation[warpcount];
    __shared__ int anywheremask;
    
    const auto stride = (length + blocksize - 1) / blockcount;
    const auto start = stride * blockIdx.x;
    const auto end = start + stride; //allow processing past end.
    __syncthreads();
    //from start to middle
    for (auto i = start + threadIdx.x; i < end; i += blockDim.x) {
        //all threads will always be active inside this loop.
        const auto a = (i < length) ? data[i] : small; //do not read past end though
        const auto foundmask = __ballot_sync(-1u, a >= threshold);
        //contains a 1 if found inside the warp.
        minlocation[warpid] = foundmask;
        __syncthreads();
        if (warpid() == 0) { //only in warp0 to reduce demand on shared memory.
            anywheremask = __ballot_sync(-1u, minlocation[laneid()]); //note that -1u assumes a block has 1024 threads, should really use a constexpr to derive the activemask from blocksize.
        }
        __syncthreads();
        if (anywheremask) {
            const auto warpfind = __ffs(anywheremask) -1;
            assert(uint32_t(warpfind) < 32);
            //do not worry about 1024 concurrent reads from shared memory, because this only happens once.
            const auto lanefind = __ffs(minlocation[warpfind]) - 1;
            assert(uint32_t(lanefind) < 32);
            //you may use an atomicOr here to signal
            //that you've found something and test that
            //value elsewhere to exit early, so other blocks also have an early out.
            return i - threadIdx.x + warpfind * 32 + lanefind;
        }
    }
    constexpr auto not_found = -1;
    return not_found; 
}

template <int blockcount, int blocksize>
__global__ findminmax(int* data, int length, int threshold, int* gmin, int* gmax) {
    assert(blockcount == blockDim.x);
    gmin[blockIdx.x] = findmin<blockcount, blocksize>(data, length, threshold);
    //now reduce the gmin array, to find the minimal value.
    //code for gmax works the same way, but traverse the data in the opposite direction.
    //do not! run findmin and findmax at the same time, because findmax needs min position as a stop.    
}

int main() {
     //init data
     
     cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //or use collaborative groups
     findminmax<<<46,1024>>><46, 1024>(data, len, t, gmin, gmax);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
     
}
```

I have not tested the code above, nor have I tried to compile it, but I hope you'll get the idea.

Pre-Ampere you can easily program your own `__reduce_XXX_sync` like so:

```
__device__ [[nodiscard]] int reduce_min_sync(int activemask, int data) {
    assert(activemask == -1); //adjust code if not all threads are active 
    data = min(data, __shfl_down_sync(activemask, 1, data);
    data = min(data, __shfl_down_sync(activemask, 2, data);
    data = min(data, __shfl_down_sync(activemask, 4, data);
    data = min(data, __shfl_down_sync(activemask, 8, data);
    data = min(data, __shfl_down_sync(activemask, 16, data);
    return data;
}
```

However if will be much faster to do be reduction using atomics

```
__device__ [[nodiscard]] int reduce_min_sync(int activemask, int data) {
    const auto starttime = clock64(); //not clock32, that is slow!
    __shared__ int s_min;
    s_min = big;
    //__syncwarp()// no need for sync, everyone agrees on s_min
    atomicMin(&s_min, data);
    __syncwarp();
    const auto endtime = clock64();
    printf("time for atomic reduction = %i cycles\n", int(endtime - starttime));
    return s_min;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Johan
I will run some experiments on this and share the results soon.

 Much appreciate the support